# Why is a leak from my freezer going down the fridge?

Tags: leak, refrigerator, freezer

The refrigerator leaks water inside itself from the freezer to the fridge. After a few days it pools on the bottom of the fridge. Wish I can send videos, its a pretty fast paced leak and happens occasionally

[image]

Comment: do you have a ice machine-is it working?

Comment: Is the freezer an auto-defrost model? If so, "fast drips, happens occasionally" would be explained. Though, you'd think they'd have a better method for managing the melted frost. Perhaps the drain tube(s) is clogged.

Comment: Model number???

Comment: Sounds like this is a top mounted freezer arrangement, yes?

Comment: It's common for defrost models to drip water down to a drain pan in the bottom of the fridge.  A refrigerator is a heat pump with a cold side and a hot side... the hot side is next to the drain pan, which makes the water evaporate.  Anyway, if the tube from freezer to drain is broken, that would cause what you see.

Comment: Find the drain, flush it out with hot water  using a turkey baster.

Comment: @Gil This comment should be turned into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm voting for auto defrost freezer with obstructed drain too, but more specifically I'm guessing the drain is blocked by ice. Mine has the freezer on bottom, so when its drain becomes blocked with ice (has happened 3 times now) I get a sudden pool of water on the kitchen floor rather than dripping down into the refrigerator.

Really the only way to check whether this is happening is to disassemble the freezer compartment and visually check.

Remove the food from the freezer compartment. Have a look at its rear wall. There's likely to be a panel with louvers, or a gap around the edges, and held in place by several screws. Remove the screws and gently wiggle the panel out. There might be a foam seal, and it may be stuck in place with a little (or a lot?) of ice. You'll also want to take care to avoid damaging the fins on the heat exchanger (or cutting your finger on them; they can be sharp!).

What you find behind that cover panel might look something like the photo below (credit: [www.indiamart.com](http://www.indiamart.com)). There's likely to be some kind of sloped drainage pan with a port at the low point. Is there an accumulation of ice in the area?

[image: freezer heat exchanger]

Comment: Ice blockage, at least in my experience, is a secondary effect.  The root cause is something (spider web, dirt, ...) that blocks the drainage tube under the refrig and causes the drain water to back up into the freezer section.  Then that water freezes, a process that continues until water starts running out of the now frozen drip tray.

Comment: I've had refrigerators/freezers freeze up like that. As I recall in one case, the drain hose clogged up with crud and ice which caused the melt water from the defrost cycle to back up in the tube and find another way out. I don't remember the make or model, but the solution was to clean out an elbow in the drain line every so often--or replace it with an elbow with a wider radius as part of a recall.

Comment: A hair dryer comes in handy for melting any ice.

Comment: @SteveSh I love this site! It's been a while since my freezer defrost flooded the kitchen floor so I checked for ice accumulation. Yep - it would have started flooding the floor again in a month or so. After clearing the ice I disassembled the drain more thoroughly than I had previously. There was a rubber coupler that took some work to remove, but sure enough it had a small aperture for water and a soggy mass of something fibrous slowing the drainage and enabling ice buildup. Thanks!

Comment: @Greg Hill - Thanks for the feedback.  Glad that worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this particular refrigerator but most of the time when this happens the solution is relatively easy to resolve. The hardest part is to first find the drain. Once you find it flush it out with hot water using a turkey baster. Caution it is clogged with ice so it may take a few minutes to be effective. Do not use to much water or it will be on the floor. once you have it open use your shop vac to suck out any food or other debris that may be in there. Now enjoy a dripless refrigerator for a while, probably lots of years.